# Highcharts xAxis categories rotation column chart

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am using the column type, the categories in xAxis rotates -45, i want text to be horizontal(0 rotation) but wrap.

using Angular 17, Bootstrap 5.

I tried these options in ts file but nothing changed:

```
xAxis: {
        categories: ['Anayeli Bautista', 'Carlos Antonio Gallegos'],
        labels: {
          style: {
            overflow: 'auto',
          whiteSpace: 'normal',
          rotation: 0 ,
          }
        }
      },
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify regex ( `\b.*?[\w]{1,10}\b` ) to the property `xaxis.labels.formatter`, which splits the long string into whole words, then we join them with the HTML break line `<br/>`

Note: this is just one way to solve your problem, you can write your own formatter to perfectly format the text

```
...
labels: {
    rotation: -45,
    formatter: function () {
      return this.value.match(/\b.*?[\w]{1,10}\b/g).join('<br/>');
    },
},
...
```

[`Stackblitz Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-stacked-bar-e4i2ph?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, it is solved using `xAxislabel` options:

```
labels: {
  style: {
    width: 20,
  },
  autoRotationLimit:20,
},
```

As auto rotation is applied if the text is within the set limit which is in default 80, if more than 80 it will wrap and not rotate.

So I set the limit to 20 so it will fit a whole word and the other word will wrap to the next line